# Configure java for rJava inside a conda environment

Tags: r, conda, rjava

On OSX 10.12.6 I've created a conda environment including R, r-rjava, and java-jdk. Specifically `which R` and `which java` point inside the env as expected while the env is activated.

However,

```
> library(rJava)
> .jinit()
```

> JavaVM: requested Java version ((null)) not available. Using Java at
>   "" instead. JavaVM: Failed to load JVM:
>   /bundle/Libraries/libserver.dylib JavaVM FATAL: Failed to load the jvm
>   library. Error in .jinit() : JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs returned -1

I see a million related posts, but none exactly with this angle. The first thing I notice is that `system("echo $JAVA_HOME")` returns the system java home instead of the env java home.

So I tried to fix this with `R CMD javareconf`. The result is that inside my `[env]/lib/R/etc` I can see two files got modified (based on the timestamps). Presumably the relevant one is Makeconf, which includes a `JAVA_HOME = [env]/jre`.

But none of this has any effect on the problem above, and `system("echo $JAVA_HOME")` still returns the system java home. Any ideas?